# List file shares on AWS Storage Gateway with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-storage-gateway

I am trying to list all fileshares on a specific Storage Gateway like so:

```py
import boto3

sg = boto3.client('storagegateway', 'us-east-1')
aws = sg.list_file_shares(
    GatewayARN = "arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:........."
)
for fileshare in aws:
    print(
    "Id: {0}\nFileShareType: {1}\nFileShareARN: {2}\nFileShareId: {3}\nFileShareStatus".format(
    FileShareInfolist[fileshareType], fileshare.FileShareARN, fileshare.FileShareId, fileshare.FileShareStatus
    )
```

I am not sure how to get the info I need. Please help.

Comment: Are you saying that the code produces an error (if so, please show it)? What is the "info you need"? What is your actual question?

Comment: I need to show following info : fileshare.FileShareARN, fileshare.FileShareId, fileshare.FileShareStatus displayed as a column for each share

Answer (score 0):

The [`list_file_shares()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/storagegateway.html#StorageGateway.Client.list_file_shares) API call returns:

```json
{
    'Marker': 'string',
    'NextMarker': 'string',
    'FileShareInfoList': [
        {
            'FileShareType': 'NFS'|'SMB',
            'FileShareARN': 'string',
            'FileShareId': 'string',
            'FileShareStatus': 'string',
            'GatewayARN': 'string'
        },
    ]
}
```

Therefore, your code would be something like:

```py
import boto3

sg_client = boto3.client('storagegateway', 'us-east-1')
response = sg_client.list_file_shares(GatewayARN = "arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:.........")

for fileshare in response['FileShareInfoList']:
    print(
        "Id: {0}\nFileShareType: {1}\nFileShareARN: {2}\nFileShareId: {3}\nFileShareStatus".format(
        fileshare['FileShareType'], fileshare['FileShareARN'], fileshare['FileShareId'], fileshare['FileShareStatus']
        )
    )
```

Comment: thank you. any idea how to format this in a column instead of row?

Comment: ```
Id: NFS
FileShareType: arn:aws:storagegateway:us-east-1:145429107744:share/share-6E229805
FileShareARN: share-6E229805
FileShareId: AVAILABLE
FileShareStatus
```

Comment: output is off any idea

Comment: What do you mean by "format this in a column"? Just on separate lines?